# Rotating the array using C

Tags: c

Why this code is giving segmentation fault error?

This is code using for loop for left shift the given array at stdin by no of rotations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *rotatebyone(int *array_input, int len_of_arr);
void rotate(int *array_input, int len_of_arr, int no_of_rota);
int main()
{

    int array1[] = { };
    int array2[] = { };
    int array3[] = { };
    int i = 0, j = 0, size_of_arr = 0, no_of_rotations = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
        //printf("%d", array1[i]);
    }

    size_of_arr = array1[0];
    no_of_rotations = array1[1];

    for (i = 0; i < size_of_arr; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array2[i]);
        //printf("%d ", array2[i]);
    }
    rotate(array2, size_of_arr, no_of_rotations);

    return 0;
}
void rotate(int *array_input, int size_of_array, int no_of_rota)
{
    int h = 0;
    for (h = 0; h < no_of_rota; h++)
    {
        rotatebyone(array_input, size_of_array);
    }
    for (h = 0; h < size_of_array; h++)
        printf("%d ", array_input[h]);
}

int *rotatebyone(int *array_input1, int len_of_arr)
{
//int array3 = {};
    int j = 0, k = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    temp = array_input1[0];
    for (k = 0; k < len_of_arr - 1; k++)
    {
        array_input1[k] = array_input1[k + 1];
    }
    array_input1[len_of_arr - 1] = temp;
    return array_input1;
}
```

Comment: `int array1[] = {};`...really?

Comment: `int array1[] = {};` --> `int array1[2] = {0};`

Comment: `int array2[] = {};` --> `int array2[size_of_arr];` and move to after `size_of_arr = array1[0];`

Comment: delete `int array3[] = {};`

Comment: Just to start...[Take a look at all errors of your code](http://ideone.com/fZCZbV)...

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  for the posted code, for both calls to `scanf()`, the only 'good' return value is 1.  Anything else indicates an error occurred.

Comment: this kind of line: int array1[] = { }; is a problem because neither the declaration nor the initializer provide the actual/desired size of the array.  So, at best the compiler will only allocate room for a single `int`.   so the accessing into the array beyond `array1[0]` is beyond the bounds of the array which is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event/  Note: the rest of the code indicates the array1[] should have room for 2 entries, so the declarations should be: `int array1[] = { 0, 0 };` or `int array1[2];`   similar considerations exist for `array2[]`

Answer (score 0):

For array2[], you have not mentioned its size. It can be evn 1000 or 10000. Better use int * array2 and allot memory through malloc.
Reg array1, it can be initialesed as int array1[2] since we know two elements are there for array1.